# como hacer funcionar JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

estoy intentando de utilizar javafx. instale jre 1.8 pero me sale varios errores Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Pck1/MainClass has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0. ya actualice el JDK por la version mas.

alguien podría ayudarme a configurar este error. se los agradecería bastante.

```html
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class MainClass extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
    
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Circle c1 = new Circle(50,50,15);
        c1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        c1.setFill(Color.rgb(170, 170, 100));
        
        Circle c2 = new Circle(75,90,20);
        c2.setStroke(Color.RED);
        c2.setFill(Color.rgb(200, 2000, 100));
        
        Pane p = new Pane();
        p.getChildren().addAll(c1);
        
        
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().add(p);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(vb);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Basic JavaFX Configuration");
        stage.setWidth(500.0);
        stage.setHeight(440.0);
        stage.show();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: ** ya actualice el JDK por la version mas**   ¿ Más qué ? ¿ más reciente ? ¿ podría decirnos cuál versión de jdk está usando ahora ?

Comment: Que pena no me di cuenta, tengo jdk 17

Comment: Jdk 17  no trae la librería de javafx puede agregarla manualmente o usar maven o gradle

Comment: Pero ya lo añadí manualmente, fui a la página de JavaFx y hize el proceso y cuando vuelvo hacer este mismo proyecto o creo otro  proyecto me vuelve a salir errores.

Comment: qué Ide o procesador de textos ? qué versión de javafx ?

Comment: Hay dos caminos, el fácil, crea una nueva aplicación con el mismo nombre (previamente quita y guarda la actual), luego copias los archivos de la vieja en el directorio correspondiente, la otra es modificar la configuración de tu proyecto para que acepte la versión actual.